# Neo4j Cypher relationship existis and collection of IDs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Neo4j Cypher query that checks if relationship exists between `User` and `entity` and returns boolean result:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = {userId} MATCH (entity) WHERE id(entity) = {entityGraphId} RETURN EXISTS( (u)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity) )
```

Please help to rewrite this query in order to be able to accept a collection of `{entityGraphIds}` instead of a single `{entityGraphId}` and check if a relationship exists between `User` and any entities with these `{entityGraphIds}`.

For example, I have `user1` and `entity1`, `entity2`. `user1` has a relationship with `entity2`. I'll pass `{user.id}` like `{userId}` and `{entity1.id, entity2.id}` like `{entityGraphIds}` and this query should return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply use the [IN operator](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#where-in-operator). Considering these parameters:

```
:params {userId: 1, entityGraphIds : [2,3,4]}
```

Then, the query:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = {userId}
MATCH (entity) WHERE id(entity) IN ({entityGraphIds})
RETURN EXISTS( (u)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity) )
```

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to return `true` when `:User` is connected to at least 1 entity, then you can simplify your query to:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity:Entity)
WHERE u.id = {userId} AND id(entity) IN ({entityGraphIds})
RETURN u IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once I'll test it I'll update here.

Comment: Thank you very much! The second query works extremely fine. Thanks for your continuous help!!!

Comment: I apologize, but I found an issue on this(second) query - 'Result not of expected size. Expected 1 row but found 2'. This error appears when the user owns 2 or more entities.

Comment: Is it a correct way to return 'RETURN count(u) > 0' instead ?

Comment: @alexanoid which version of neo4j are you using? I'm running 3.2.1 with this initial data set `create (user:User {id : 1})
create (e1:Entity {id : 2})
create (e2:Entity {id : 3})
create (e3:Entity {id : 4})
create (user)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(e1)
create (user)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(e2)` and with this query `OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity:Entity)
WHERE u.id = {userId} AND entity.id IN ({entityGraphIds})
RETURN u IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: All works fine which these parameters: `:params {userId: 1, entityGraphIds : [2,3]}`.

Comment: I use Neo4j 3.2.3

Comment: All working fine here with a docker container (3.2.3). Can you share your data set and the query you are using? Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you please try to create a few more users (not a single one) and add them as owners of entities ? In my schema one entity can have 0..N owners. One user can own 0..N entities... MANY-2-MANY relationship. Query with error - `MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = {userId} MATCH (entity) WHERE id(entity) IN {entityGraphIds} RETURN EXISTS( (u)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity) )` and the working query - `OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(entity) WHERE u.id = {userId} AND id(entity) IN ({entityGraphIds}) RETURN count(u) > 0`

Comment: @alexanoid sure. give me some minutes. i'm in the mobile phone now! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153991/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-alexanoid).